# Google App Engine: Why are key-only datastore queries costing me 1 READ plus 1 SMALL?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Google App Engine java application, which performs well for my needs, but I'd like to optimize for datastore operation costs.

I understand that small datastore operations are [free](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing), and from the same article that key-only queries use small operations...

> Small datastore operations include calls to allocate datastore ids or keys-only queries

... so I expected that if I do a key-only query, and use the key from the first retrieved 'entity' to get the full entity then it should cost me 1 small operation, plus one (large) read operation in total - only the latter of which costs money. This is exactly the same logic used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769162/why-are-keys-only-queries-free) Stack Overflow question. If I ran the same thing by just doing a regular query and fetching the first entity, it would cost me 1 + 1 (large) read.

But... when I run appstats on my application, what I see is that the query costs me 1 Read, plus 1 small, and then I also have to pay for the get:

> @15ms datastore_v3.RunQuery real=8ms api=0ms cost=80 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:1, DATASTORE_SMALL:1]
>
> @6ms datastore_v3.Get real=7ms api=0ms cost=70 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:1]

... so this is costing me 1 more read than I expected, and 1 extra small operation compared with what I was doing before.

Example bit of java code looks like this:

```
Query query = new Query(<Entity Name>).setKeysOnly();
Filter filter = new FilterPredicate(<Field Name>, Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, <Some Value>);
query.setFilter(filter);
List<Entity> resultsSet = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(<Max Rows>));
Entity entity = datastore.get(resultsSet.get(0).getKey());
```

Question is: am I implementing this wrong, or did I just misunderstand how the pricing works? Thanks.

Comment: Well you have two queries there. The first is `datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(<Max Rows>)).get(0).getKey()`, the second is `datastore.get(key);`.

Comment: Yes, understood. But the question is: why does the keysOnly query (the first one), cost one small read, plus one (regular) read - when the documentation says 'small datastore operations include... keys-only queries'? The fact that the get (the second 'query') costs one (regular) read is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: There's also the matter of the filter. A filter usually requires a sort operation which doesn't count as a small operation. I'll try to find a documentation link for it.

Comment: Really? I haven't seen anything in the documentation indicating that. It has to be using an indexed property or the query wouldn't work at all - in this case it will be one of the built-in indexes, rather than a composite index.

Comment: "Queries on keys use indexes just like queries on properties and require custom indexes in the same cases, with a couple of exceptions: inequality filters or an ascending sort order on the key do not require a custom index, but a descending sort order on the key does." (Source: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#Datastore_Key_filters) I wonder if that helps much... Sorry, can't find much more than that but it sounds like a regular filter operation.

Comment: @konqi - I think that's a reference about queries based on key criteria, whereas my question is about keys-only queries that just return the key part of entities. What I should do is try an experiment doing a query without a filter at all, and see if that still costs 1 read for the query itself, plus 1 small for each returned result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/03/Google-Cloud-Datastore-simplifies-pricing-cuts-cost-dramatically-for-most-use-cases.html?m=1) new post in Google Cloud Platform Blog - which is about their NEW pricing structure - actually clarifies in writing how the old pricing is supposed to work re small read operations...

> Small ops (projections and keys-only queries) will stay the same in only charging a single read for the entire query

So this confirms / provides source for what others said - key-only queries cost a single read - and that the old pricing documentation was not very clear / was misleading! But all moot now since pricing is changing as of July!

Answer (score 1):

The pricing document that you linked to clearly indicates that every query costs 1 read. Regular queries also cost 1 read per entity, while keys-only queries do not charge per entity.

So, if you want to retrieve one entity, using a keys-only query and then `get` to retrieve the entity is more expensive. If you retrieve two entities, it gets even. If you want to retrieve thousands of entities, a keys-only query is basically free compared to the regular query.

Comment: Thanks. It does clearly say regular queries cost 1 regular read, plus one per entity returned. But it also clearly says 'small datastore operations include... keys-only queries'. So it says two things that are either  ambiguous or contradictory. You're saying that I should understand what the documentation to mean is: "small datastore operations include... keys returned as part of key-only queries (but the actual query still costs 1 read)"?

Comment: May I ask: are you definitively telling me that is how the pricing is intended to work, or are you just giving me your interpretation of what the documentation says? (By the way: I think there are at least two other stack overflow answers that contradict this answer - one is the one I quoted above, and the other is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015190/cost-of-keys-only-query-compared-to-get-query-google-app-engine?rq=1) one).

Comment: Between the documentation and the logs that you posted, it's very clear.

Comment: Besides, I read about it in one of the Google's posts. Note that 10,000,000 keys-only queries cost $6, so what is exactly are you trying to save? Do you already run like a billion of such queries?

Comment: do you have link to that google post please? That would definitively answer the question. Thanks.